# Problema com css animation chamada por uma função javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho uma página `index.html` que contém um **`<p id="valor">`**

Que é atualizado através de uma WebSocket utilizando **javascript**.

Sempre que servidor envia a mensagem a função **`atualizar(valor)`** é chamada:

```js
function atualizar(valor) {
  document.getElementById("valor").innerText = valor;
  document.getElementById("valor").style.animation = "example 1s 1";
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

#valor {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes example {
  50% {
    font-size: 45px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="atualizar(this.value);" />
<p id="valor">Meu texto padrão</p>
```

A ideia é que sempre ao atualizar o valor ele faça com o texto um animação *Scale* e *Shake Effect*. O problema é que ele **só funciona na primeira vez** que a função é chamada.

Comment: Matheus, a resposta foi suficiente para resolver seu problema? Se sim, por favor aceite a questão como resolvida, senão coloque suas dúvidas. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Exemplo em `javascript` puro:

```js
function atualizar(valor) {
  textBox = document.getElementById("valor");
  textBox.innerText = valor;
  requestAnimation(textBox);
}

var requestAnimation = function(obj) {
  obj.style.animation = 'none';
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
     obj.style.animation = 'example 1s';
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

#valor {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes example {
  50% {
    font-size: 45px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="atualizar(this.value);" />

<p id="valor">Meu texto padrão</p>
```

---

#### Observações:

- A função **`requestAnimation`** será utilizada para fazer uma nova requisição de animação
- Com isso sua animação e não ficará mais travada e pode ser executada quantas vezes quiser
- Para exemplificar de forma simples nesse caso utilizei o evento **`onBlur`**
- Para testar basta mudar o texto e tirar o foco da caixa de texto que a animação começará
- Se quiser colocar em outro evento, por exemplo, no clique do mouse

  - Basta chamar a função `atualizar(valor)` no evento `onClick` do botão
  - Não esquecer de capturar o valor do seu `input` usando outra estratégia
- Observe que para o exemplo funcionar coloquei um fundo escuro pois sua fonte é branca

---

#### Referência:

- [How to restart CSS Animation with minimal impact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073747/how-to-restart-css-animation-with-minimal-impact)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074584/5626568